# Display data as a mindmap

Tags: jquery, mindmapping

On [this screencast](http://www.nordicdb.com/), at time 16:15, Paul Nielsen talks about displaying data as a mindmap.
How could I do that?

Comment: http://code.google.com/p/js-mindmap/ looks interesting.

Comment: http://morrisonpitt.com/jsPlumb/html/demo2.html

Comment: Hi Philip, another one I like: Demo: http://movie-map.com/city+of+god.html ; Code: http://movie-map.com/elements/objects/related.js . It's a personal project but can't find the License :(

Comment: check out http://mindmeister.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are looking for a generic graph visualisation tool have a look at [www.graphviz.org/](http://www.graphviz.org/) here is their [Gallery](http://www.graphviz.org/Gallery.php)

Answer (score 3):

There's [this one](http://kenneth.kufluk.com/google/js-mindmap/) based on Jquery

Comment: its a comment not an answer.

Answer (score 1):

The open source tool Freemind [freemind.sourceforge.net/](http://freemind.sourceforge.net/) uses an XML file format with file extension .mm. You could generate the file then provide a download link.